# Ошибка "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Tags: php, mysql

При добавление записи в бд возникает ошибка, может кто-нибудь помочь её исправить?

Ошибка:

```
РћС€РёР±РєРё Р·Р°РїСЂРѕСЃР°: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Код добавления:

```
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `logdb`.`logtable` (`25i`, `658c`, `2sy`, `2st`, `66t`) VALUES ('" . $i25 . "','" . $c658 . "','" . $sy2 . "','" . $st2 . "','" . $t66 . "','" . $in25 . "')")or die("Ошибки запроса: " . mysql_error());
```

Данные в переменных RSA шифрую, подозреваю, что ошибка возникает из-за возникновения \t\n после шифрации.

Comment: я не спец в php, но по-моему вы забыли слово values как минимум.

Comment: @Denis Хм, точняк, как я этого не заметил) Та ошибка исчезла, но появилась другая `РћС€РёР±РєРё Р·Р°РїСЂРѕСЃР°: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас 5 столбцов:

`(25i, 658c, 2sy, 2st, 66t)`

а значений для вставки 6:

```
('" . $i25 . "','" . $c658 . "','" . $sy2 . "','" . $st2 . "','" . $t66 . "','" . $in25 . "')
```

Соответственно, вы и получаете ошибку - количество столбцов не соответствует числу значений.

Кажется, вы забыли указать столбец `25in` (`$in25`):

```
(25i, 658c, 2sy, 2st, 66t, 25in)
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло)